# Specifying a relative path in web.xml when debugging a servlet with Eclipse's WTP Tomcat Server?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, relative-path

I'm trying to specify a relative directory in the web.xml file.  I basically want it to read the "data" folder underneath "web-inf", but nothing I've tried seems to work.

"/data" translates to the data folder in the root directory (I'm using windows).

"data" translates to "C:\Program Files\Eclipes\data"

"${CATALINA_HOME}/[etc...]" doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

WTP uses the variable "${catalina.home}", not "${CATALINA_HOME}"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this to obtain an absolute path from your relative path:

```
ServletContext ctx = ....;
String absolutePath = ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/" + relativePath);
```